# Allow smaller bounties for the purposes of rewarding a good answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I know and agree with the minimum bounty of `+50`.

However, as I understand it, the reason of this is to make sure that people cannot get on the "Featured" queue with a trivial bounty.

However, when a bounty is posted simply to reward a good answer, the purpose is not to get onto the "Featured" queue. Therefore, I suggest that this type of bounty be allowed to take lower values. For example, a low-rep user like myself could give `+20` bounties more easily than `+50`'s.

Obviously, this would require the user to select the question beforehand.

Comment: Do you mean "select the answer beforehand" in the last sentence?

Comment: @Scimonster: Awarding points for good questions should be equally possible ;-)

Comment: @Scimonster to prevent abuse, you'd have to select the question. Otherwise, people could put themselves on the "featured" queue with a 20 pt. bounty and then reward a new answer rather than an older one.

Comment: I don't understand the need some people have to award an already accepted answer with a bounty.

Comment: So you want sockpuppets to get to a voting reputation level immediately, without the community supervision that bounties currently enjoy? Because that'll be what this is going to be used for; transferring rep surreptitiously between fraudulent accounts.

Comment: @MartinPieters Oh, I never considered that as a possibility.

Comment: @KevinB, there are several good reasons. 1. Gratitude is something most humans like to give and receive. 2. Being known as someone generous with bounties can help your future questions attract extra effort. 3. The bounty will draw attention to both the question and the answer; this likely magnifies the reward to the answerer as many upvote their answer. It may also return some or all of the bounty to the asker as many upvote their question.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

On one hand it seems like a good idea.

But on the other hand, allowing such low bounties could defeat their purpose, in a way. A bounty would not be something "special" anymore. Answerers could come to "expect" a small bounty when they think their answer is good enough.

So perhaps it's better to keep a relatively high value for the minimum bounty, so that not rewarding an answer with a bounty can continue to be considered perfectly normal.

Comment: Indeed - an upvote already awards 10 points.  If an answer is good, it will get several, and easily reach the 50 point minimum threshold anyway.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Of course the times you especially want to give a bounty would when the answer _doesn't_ seem get much recognition (e.g. in a niche tag).

Comment: @Nateowami My point was more that you can give 10 points for free anyway.  If you asked the question, that raises to 25.  There really isn't much of a jump here to 50.

Comment: I agree. We shouldn't be lowering the standard on what's exceptional. Society does that enough already.

Comment: Best I can tell, if you want to award a bonus to an answer by someone else to a question of yours to which you also provided your own answer, the minimum bonus is +100. This has stopped me from awarding a bonus to an answer at least once in recent months. I would be in favor of lowering the minimum bonus to +50 in such a case.

Comment: "Answerers could come to "expect" a small bounty when they think their question is good enough." Sounds like a waiter that expects to be tipped for good service.

Comment: @j08691 ...which means you agree or you don't? I've heard varied opinions about tipping waiters (it highly depends on each country's culture)

Answer (score 41):

I don't think the lower value of bounty is necessary.

When you upvote the answer and accept it, you give that user 25 rep. It's  more than your bounty would be.

If the problem/question is really interesting, you can put up a 50 rep bounty. You actually have > 800 rep, so there is no need to give less: you can put up a 50 rep bounty.

The users you wrote about, users with low reputation, in my view don't want to use bounties. Often they reward an answer by accepting or upvoting this answer. Many of them don't know that bounties exist.

Comment: Important to note the rep from upvotes and accepted answers is *created*, not *given*.  The person performing these actions doesn't lose any rep.